# What is first argument in 'JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog() here?

Tags: java, swing

Here is the below code snippet, where i would like to display the dialog using `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()` by setting its parent as `resultsTablePanel`:

```
public class SearchResultsTablePanel extends JPanel{...}

public class DefaultSearchListener{

   private SearchResultsTablePanel resultsTablePanel = null;

   public void f(X x) {
       int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                resultsTablePanel,
                "hai",
                "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            // do something
        } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            // do something
        } else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            // do something
        }
   }
}
```

My question:

For java swing api `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`,
Do i need to pass `resultsTablePanel` as first argument?

or

Do i need to pass `JOptionPane.getframeforcomponent(resultsTablePanel)` as first argument?

Comment: As described by the JavaDocs, you pass it reference of a Component which acts as the parent for the dialog

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter.

As part of the processing, `JOptionPane` invokes `getWindowForComponent` on the argument before passing it through to the underlying `JDialog` (which is slightly more general).

As for the implicit question "What's the difference anyway?", well this has to do with modality. Here I would urge you to read [Oracle's guide to modality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

`JOptionPane` uses the default modality type for `JDialog`, which is the Application-modal from the guide above. This means that the dialog will block input to all windows in the application, *except windows that have the dialog as the parent*. Hence, if you open 2 dialogs that have the same parent - you're in trouble, but if one has the other as the parent - then the child has controls and will transfer them to their parent once closed.

Comment: As you are talking about modality, i did not try using the existing `class XDialog extends JDialog{}` 
where the constructor calls `super( owner, title, type );`
here `owner` is `JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent ( resultsTablePanel )`
and type is `Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL`

Comment: @overexchange Uh... Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: my question is, Instead of using `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`, if i inherit `XDialog`, i can create the Yes/NO buttons, but not sure, how to print the msg "Hai" as per the above query. How do i do that?

Comment: If instead of using `JOptionPane` you decide to use raw `JDialog`, then the dialog will have a content pane for you to add arbitrary components to, in whatever layout you need.

Comment: yes you are right, but in this approach which `Component` do i use to display string "Hai"? For YES/NO i will use JButton.

Comment: @overexchange A `JLabel` I would guess?