# Error :Frames cannot be converted to components?

Tags: java, swing

I am getting an error at the following statement

```
public class project {

JFrame start ; 
 JButton submit; 
 JButton cancel ;
 JButton fp ;
 JTextField username; 
 JPasswordField pass ;
 JLabel uname ;
 JLabel pawd ;

    project()
{
    start = new JFrame("Project");
   submit = new JButton("Submit");
   cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
   fp = new JButton("Forgot Password ?") ;    
 uname = new JLabel("Username");
 pass = new JPasswordField();
 pawd = new JLabel("Password");
 username = new JTextField();
 start.setBounds(300,400,900,900);
 start.setResizable(true);
 start.setVisible(true);
 uname.setBounds(180,200,80,25);
 pawd.setBounds(230,225,80,25);

submit.setBounds(250,350,90,25);
 cancel.setBounds(3400,350,90,25);
 username.setBounds(300,200,100,25);
 pass.setBounds(300,230,100,25);
 fp.setBounds(420,215,125,25);
 start.add(submit);
 start.add(cancel);
 start.add(fp);
 start.add(username);
 start.add(pass);
 start.add(username);
 
 start.add(uname);
 start.add(pawd);
 submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
         submitperformed(ae);
     }
 });
 
}

public void submitperformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
   
    if((username.getText()).equals("root") && (pass.getPassword().equals("11223344")))
    {
       start.setVisible(false);
    }
    
    else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Wrong Username or Password","Error Mesage", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            
   
}
public void cancelperformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
   
   System.exit(0);
           
   
}
public static void main(String []s)
{
    project a = new project();
}
```

}

Incompatible type : frame "project" cannot be converted to component !

I got a similar question at [What is first argument in 'JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog() here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256751/what-is-first-argument-in-joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-here)     but it was a bit too complex.
Now, from what my teacher told me , we pass the object of current class as the argument in place of where i have passed this. But "this" too does the job. So what does the above mentioned error mean ??
Can anyone explain this simply than the above link ??

## UPDATED :

This was the whole code. Actually as of now, i have no idea of the components concept that you were talking about. I have heard it a few times. Is it a class or a package ?? Could you please throw some light on that ?? Shall be grateful and how does null work when we are supposed to provide a component argument ??

Another thing !!
I am attaching a snapshot of the result of above code. Ignore the buttons and the username label. Just Notice the password label.Now that's not the position i have set the bounds according to. No matter whatever bounds i set, its position doesn't change. Its been frustrating, i dont know whats causing this problem. Is it something to do with adding labels and buttons before setting their bounds or something like that ??Can you look through it please and find out what is happening out ??[image: faulty code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current object, which is referred to by the `this` parameter, does not extend an AWT or Swing Component, and that's why you're seeing the error exactly as the message is telling. This involves several issues including 1) understanding just what `this` means, 2) (and sometimes) understanding what it means inside of inner classes, 3) understanding that method parameters must be a type or sub-type of the parameter in the method declaration...

The solution is simple: make sure you pass a reference to a GUI component or to `null` into that method's first parameter. It's better to avoid using null if the JOptionPane is being used as a dialog window off of another main window.

Note that if you need more help, and especially if this answer doesn't solve your problem, then please tell us more about your problem and show more code, especially the code around the JOptionPane method call, and also that shows the class declarations so we can see what type your class is.

Use a Swing component as the JOptionPane's first parameter, here `start` would work nicely:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(start, "Wrong Username or Password","Error Mesage", 
       JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Also,

- Your getPassword() returns a char array, not a String. You need Arrays.equals for comparison.
- Avoid using null layouts and setBounds as this leads to hard to maintain ugly code (as you're finding out) and often to ugly GUI's. Instead use layout managers.

---

For example using GridBagLayout:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Project2 {
   private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 10;
   private static final int I_GAP = 3;
   private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField();
   private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

   public Project2() {
      userNameField.setColumns(COLUMN_COUNT);
      passwordField.setColumns(COLUMN_COUNT);

      GridBagConstraints gbc = getGbc(0, 0, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("User Name:"), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
      mainPanel.add(userNameField, gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(0, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 1, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
      mainPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y, int fill) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP);
      gbc.fill = fill;

      return gbc;
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userNameField.getText();
   }

   public char[] getPassword() {
      return passwordField.getPassword();
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Project2 project2 = new Project2();

      int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, project2.getMainPanel(),
            "Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      if (input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         if (project2.getUserName().equals("root") && 
               Arrays.equals(project2.getPassword(), "11223344".toCharArray())) {
            // you're good
         } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(project2.getMainPanel(),
                  "error message", "Error Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: For time being, i am running it using null. Because i don't completely understand swing yet .But thanks anyway. I will now google for the components section that you talked about and then understand the other solution.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan: show us the code for the class, and we'll likely be able to give you a better explanation of things.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan: Change to: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(start, "Wrong Username or Password","Error Mesage", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);` More recommendations coming

Comment: It worked !! But i am curious. How did that work when "this" didn't?? PLus, i have another problem (sorry), have attached the snapshot !

Comment: @KirtyBhushan: `this` only works if your class extends a Swing component which yours does not. Your project class extends nothing. Note that you should not be using null layout and `setBounds(...)` for that leads to ugly hard to maintain code.

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft . That was a much tidy code. Although it will take me a while to understand every bit of it. But still i am highly grateful for what i got to understand.